# Ubuntu - mv: moving a directory

Tags: ubuntu, directory, filepath, mv

I'm still new to Ubuntu and the commands... and i'm trying to move jdk1.7.0_02 directory to a file/directory path using this command..

```
sudo mv ./jdk1.7.0_02/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
```

i've already uncompressed a zipped jdk7u2 folder using the sudo command. it extract into the jdk1.7.0_02 directory

i even went to this [Examples of mv commands](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/tasks/mv2.html)

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/tasks/mv2.html

so i tried this:

```
sudo mv jdk1.7.0_02 ./jdk1.7.0_02/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
```

got this error:

```
mv: cannot move ‘jdk1.7.0_02’ to ‘./jdk1.7.0_02/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0’: No such file or directory
```

so please anyone can help me understand and solve this... thanks so much :D

Comment: You miss a ` ` (blank) in the first form and on the second form you have a `.` (dot) too much. The target is an absolute path if it starts with `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mv` takes two arguments source and destination. `sudo mv ./jdk1.7.0_02/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0` command has no destination. `sudo mv jdk1.7.0_02 ./jdk1.7.0_02/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0` in this command you are moving directory inside itself. Consider cutting a directory in Windows and pasting it by going inside that. That is exactly what you are doing. What you should rather do is something like `sudo mv jdk1.7.0_02 jdk1.7.0`. That makes source and destination separate and not overlapping.

Comment: i did what u said.. is this how it supposed to be after i keyed in my password? `preeya@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo mv jdk1.7.0_02 jdk1.7.0
[sudo] password for preeya: 
preeya@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ `

Comment: Output is fine. `mv` command works in two ways. Either it will do cut paste or rename. What you have done is essentially renamed directory.